# String to vector of parsed values

Tags: rust

With lot of compiler errors and documentation browsing I came up with this function.

```
use std::io;
use std::io::Read;
use std::str::FromStr;
use std::fmt::Debug;

fn parse_vec<T>(a: &String) -> Vec<T>
    where T: FromStr, <T as FromStr>::Err: Debug {

    a.split_whitespace()
         .filter_map(|word| word.parse().ok())
         .collect()
}

fn main() {
    let mut all_input = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_to_string(&mut all_input)
        .expect("io::stdin().read_to_string(&mut all_input) error");

    let v: Vec<i32> = parse_vec(&all_input);
    println!("{}", v[0] + v[1]);
    println!("{}", all_input);
}
```

1. What does `<T as FromStr>::Err: Debug` mean? It's there because compiler suggested it. I don't know what it is.
2. Can the function `parse_vec` be shortened?
3. If I change `parse_vec` to take ownership of the string `fn parse_vec<T>(a: String) -> Vec<T>` would the memory of `all_input` string be freed after `parse_vec` finishes?
4. Is there a way to do this without intermediate string for reading input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `<T as FromStr>` is unnecessary; you can just use `T`.  It's used to refer specifically to `T`'s implementation of the `FromStr` trait.  In this case, the code isn't ambiguous enough to need that level of clarification.

   `<T as FromStr>::Err` is referring to the [`Err` type associated with `FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html#associatedtype.Err) -- if the conversion fails, what is the error type?

   `where <T as FromStr>::Err: Debug` requires that, whatever `T::Err` is, it has to implement the `Debug` trait.  This clause is not necessary with your current code: I removed it and it was fine.  In a previous iteration of your code, you probably used either [`unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap) or [`expect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.expect) instead of [`ok`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.ok).  Both `unwrap` and `expect` require that the `Result`'s error type (which is `<T as FromStr>::Err` here) implements `Debug` (you can see this in the documentation: the methods are defined in an `impl` block with `where E: Debug`), as the debug representation will be used in the panic message if the `Result` is an `Err`.
2. Well, you can get rid of the `<T as FromStr>::Err: Debug` clause.  Beyond that, I don't see what you could remove without changing what the function does.
3. Unless you returned it or stored it somewhere else, yes.  That's how ownership works.
4. No.
5. You should almost *never* use `&String`; `&str` works with more types.  The only thing `&String` gives you in addition is access to `String::capacity` which isn't really useful when reading.